# Can't install ARM64 aptly

Tags: arm64

I am doing everything as described here http://repo.aptly.info/
inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aptly.list:

```
deb http://repo.aptly.info/ squeeze main
```

but

```
root@comp:/etc/apt# apt-get install aptly
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package aptly
```

I run on ARM64 computer

```
root@comp:/etc/apt# uname -m
aarch64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `aptly` doesn't have aarch64-binaries as I see.

Comment: But I did it before!!

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: According to http://repo.aptly.info/dists/squeeze/Release : Architectures: amd64 i386

Comment: it is very strange. I have another arm64 computer where aptly is running about month as I remember... some downgrade?

Comment: Maybe it came with the OS, hence the question.

Comment: Oh! I have Debian 11 aarm64 , probably aptly is in their repositories

Comment: 1.4.0 is in Debian 11